# Calling a setuptools entry point from within the library

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging

I have a setuptools-based Python (3.5) project with multiple scripts as entry points similar to the following:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'main-prog=scripts.prog:main',
        'prog-viewer=scripts.prog_viewer:main'
    ]}
```

So there is supposed to be a main script, run as `main-prog` and an auxiliary script `prog-viewer` (which does some Tk stuff).

The problem is that I want to be able to run the `prog-viewer` in a `Popen` subprocess from `main-prog` (or rather form my library) without having to resort to manually figuring out the paths and then adapt to the different OS. Also, what do I do when my PATH contains a script with the same name that does not belong to my library? Can I tell my program to `Popen(scripts.prog_viewer:main)`?

Comment: Can't you just do `from scripts.prog_viewer import main; main()`?

Comment: @cel I need to run it in a subprocess though.

Answer (score 2):

You could run a python command with Popen, for example:

```
Popen('python -c "from scripts.prog import main; main()"', shell=True)
```

Comment: I would sleep better if I knew that this is the proper way of doing it and not the hack that it looks like. :)

Comment: @Debilski Why would you call this a hack? If you want to run it using the subprocess module and you don't want to call the entrypoint directly, then this is the way to go.

Comment: No offence meant, I just would have thought that something like this is already in some setuptools or pkg_resources module. Also, if I ever change the entry point then I need search for that string. (And it is much less clear what is running from just looking at the process table; that might also make debugging harder because argv[0] is then '-c' instead of the script.)

Comment: `Popen([sys.executable, '-m', 'scripts.prog'])` might actually be a nicer alternative. Not sure about the caveats, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Multiprocessing module, which will also run your code as a subprocess. e.g.,

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from scripts.prog import main
# or 
# from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
# main = load_entry_point('your-package', 'console_scripts', 'main_prog')

p = Process(main)
p.start()
p.join()
```